How can I see contents of maintainer scripts of apt packages?
In rpm I can type
rpm -qp --scripts nginx-full_1.18.0-6ubuntu14.4_amd64.rpm

and see the script of the package.
Is there something similar in apt?

There are 4 control scripts for apt packages: (See here)

preinst: before the installation of the files into the systems file
hierarchy
postinst: after the installation
prerm: before the uninstallation
postrm: after the uninstallation

Reading scripts of already installed packages is easiest. Here you can find the scripts located at:
/var/lib/dpkg/info/PACKAGE-NAME.preinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/PACKAGE-NAME.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/PACKAGE-NAME.prerm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/PACKAGE-NAME.postrm

So you can view all 4 scripts with this command:
cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/PACKAGE-NAME.{pre,post}{inst,rm}

For packages not installed, you have to download the package and unpack the content:
apt-get --download-only install PACKAGE-NAME
dpkg-deb -e /var/cache/apt/archives/PACKAGE-NAME YOUR-DIRECTORY

This will also extract the file control.tar.gz inside YOUR-DIRECTORY, and this will now contain the 4 control scripts, as well as md5 sums and some other stuff.
